# Pass scope variable from directive to it's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is possibly easy, but I have browsed the different questions here on SO and in the Angular documentation and can't really find what I'm looking for.

In a directive:

```
function ssKendoGrid() {
    return {
        scope: {
            dataSource: "="
        },
        template: "<div kendo-grid k-options='gridOptions'></div>",
        controller: "ssKendoGridCtrl",
    }
}
```

That uses the controller:

```
function ssKendoGridCtrl($scope) {
    alert($scope.dataSource);
    //other stuff
}
```

If I want to access the value of `dataSource` I assumed I'd be able to do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ss-kendo-grid data-source="test"></div>
</div>
```

`MyController` is:

```
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.test = "Tested";
}
```

But it comes as undefined when I try to `alert($scope.dataSource);` the value..

Now I know I can do this:

```
<div ss-kendo-grid="test"></div>
```

And access it in the directive and controller like this:

```
return {
    scope: {
        ssKendoGrid: "="
    },
    template: "<div kendo-grid k-options='gridOptions'></div>",
    controller: "ssKendoGridCtrl"
}

//In controller
alert($scope.ssKendoGrid);
```

But I would like to be able to pass in a JSON object to do various things with and this doesn't seem as clean as in the markup I'd like it to be more intuitive to look at the html and know what the `dataSource` is.

What I'm really looking for is an understanding of what I'm doing wrong, why doesn't this work?? I've obviously not got the right understanding of how to pass various things to the isolated scope of the directive.

**SOLVED**

So, turns out I was using the wrong attribute name. HTML5 recognizes `data-` as a valid attribute, and Angular ignores the fact that `data-` is prefixed on the variable, which means that I would need to access the variable this way:

HTML:

```
<div ss-kendo-grid data-source="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
return {
    scope: {
        dataSource: "=source"
    },
    template: "<div kendo-grid k-options='gridOptions'></div>",
    controller: "ssKendoGridCtrl"
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out I was using the wrong attribute name. HTML5 recognizes data- as a valid attribute, and Angular ignores the fact that data- is prefixed on the variable, which means that I would need to access the variable this way:

HTML:

```
<div ss-kendo-grid data-source="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
return {
    scope: {
        dataSource: "=source"
    },
    template: "<div kendo-grid k-options='gridOptions'></div>",
    controller: "ssKendoGridCtrl"
}
```

And a better convention is to simply not use a directive with "data-" at the beginning of it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to access the directive scope variable as

```
<div ss-kendo-grid data-source="test"></div>
```

similarly as you name the directive in the HTML markup

Comment: Doh... can't believe I missed snake-case, but I still get undefined when I use the above?

Comment: is test defined in your app controller?

Comment: Yes, added code above to explain. But once again, if I change code to point to `ss-kendo-grid="test"` it works just fine, so I know it's not a variable problem.

Comment: try to include restrict:'A' in directive and the check

Comment: Just figured it out, posted above. I was using "data-" as a prefix, which is a valid HTML5 attribute, which Angular ignored...

Answer (score -1):

```
invite.directive('googlePlaces', function (){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    // transclude:true,
    scope: {location:'=location'},
    template: '<input id="google_places_ac" name="google_places_ac" type="text" class="input-block-level"/>',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#google_places_ac")[0], {});
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        scope.location = place.geometry.location.lat() + ',' + place.geometry.location.lng();
        console.log(scope.location);
        scope.$apply();
        // scope.$apply(function() {
          // scope.location = location;
        // });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: You need to add details and explanations to your answer.